# How do I create a function to rotate a rectangle about its origin?

Tags: functions, geometry

I am new to Mathematica and was trying some new things.

I wanted to rotate a rectangle using a rotation matrix by any angle theta from say o to 2pi.

I could do it using predefined Mathematica functions.

**R = Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}]; Animate[Graphics[GeometricTransformation[R, RotationMatrix[[Theta]]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {[Theta], 0, 2 [Pi]}]**

But, say I want to write the 2x2 rotation matrix as a function and do it then how would i proceed?

I defined a 2x2 rotation matrix Rot and tried multiplying every coordinate of the rectangle, but I get an error and the rectangle doesn't rotate

I did the following:

Rot[[Theta]] = {{Cos[[Theta]], -Sin[[Theta]]}, {Sin[[Theta]], Cos[[Theta]]}};

R = Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}]; Animate[Graphics[GeometricTransformation[R, Rot[[Theta]]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {[Theta], 0, 2 [Pi]}]

Is there a simple way to do this by just defining a function and then using it?[image]

Comment: 1. Don't use `MatrixForm[]` here, as it is only intended for output formatting. 2. `RotationMatrix[]` is built-in.

Comment: I don't want to use the inbuilt Mathematica function RotationMatrix[].  But instead define a function for the 2x2 rotation matrix and then use it to rotate the rectangle as shown in the image.     Thanks

Comment: Then, you can just do `With[{θ = π/6}, Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}], {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}]]]`. But, it seems you have a more fundamental problem. Execute `Remove[Rot]`, and try using `Rot[θ_] := {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}`. (Note the difference!)

Comment: Thanks,     but if I wanted to do something like this:       Rot[\[Theta]_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], 
    Cos[\[Theta]]}};

R = Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}];
Animate[Show[Graphics[R, Rot[\[Theta]]], Axes -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]     , Where initially I have defined a function then how do I proceed?     It is similar to the image posted initially

Comment: It should work. From your screenshot, it seems you used `Rot` for something different, but forgot to clear it.

Comment: @J.M.  Is there any way that I can do this without using the inbuilt function like Geometric Transformation and multiply every coordinate of the rectangle with the rotation matrix function that we have defined to get the whole rectangle to rotate?

Comment: The `Rectangle[]` object is always axis-aligned from its arguments, so if you want something with rotatable coordinates, use a `Polygon[]`. With that, you can now use a replacement rule like `v_?VectorQ :> RotationMatrix[θ].v`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Animate[
 Graphics[{Red, 
   GeometricTransformation[Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}], 
    RotationMatrix[\[Theta]]]},
  Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}],
 {\[Theta], 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

As per your comment, if you do not want to use the built in `RotationMatrix` then please see this:

[image]

...and this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.   But instead of using RotationMatrix[\[Theta]], I want to define a 2x2 Rotation Matrix say Rot[\[Theta]_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], 
    Cos[\[Theta]]}}; and then use this function to rotate the rectangle. Also, it would be helpful if I could use Show[] in Animate alongwith PlotRange                       Thanks

Comment: @VarunKulkarni explain why you want to use `Show`

Comment: R = Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}]; Animate[Graphics[GeometricTransformation[R, RotationMatrix[[Theta]]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {[Theta], 0, 2 [Pi]}]                     This is how I have done ,  but now I want to define a function for that, and that function is a 2x2 Rotation matrix  ....Heres what I am trying               Rot[[Theta]_] := {{Cos[[Theta]], -Sin[[Theta]]}, {Sin[[Theta]], Cos[[Theta]]}}; R = Rectangle[{-2.5, -0.5}, {2.5, 0.5}]; Animate[Show[Graphics[R, Rot[[Theta]]], Axes -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}], {[Theta], 0, 2 [Pi]}]

Comment: @VarunKulkarni before doing any of this you need to learn basic Mathematica syntax. `{[Theta], 0, 2 [Pi]}` is invalid, `Sin[[Theta]]` is invalid etc, `Show` is redundant, and so on

Comment: Yes, this seems to work good.  Yes, will study the syntax.   Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch the user probably did not type this as it appears; the StackExchange software eats ``\`` if one isn't careful. I think the syntax was most likely valid.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Is there any way that I can do this without using the function Geometric Transformation?    Like, multiply every coordinate of the rectangle with the rotation matrix function that is defined and then try to rotate thee whole rectangle

Comment: @OleksandrR. yes fair point